# Unintentionally on camera in a recorded meeting - want to be edited out

Tags: meetings, privacy, reputation

I attended a company Teams meeting for training that was being recorded and after a few minutes accidentally turned on my camera and was unaware. Needless to say, it's unflattering! I looked rather dishevelled on the day, a bit unkempt and very much exhausted and washed out - not the image I would like to present to the world. I was continuing to work during the meeting and hence only listened in and did not look at the screen. I only discovered 10 days later that I had been on camera and I was the only person on camera during this meeting, so I appear throughout for 30 minutes. It's cringing. I asked the person who recorded it to edit me out by placing a black square in the place where I appear. They agreed but have not actioned it.
Does an employer need to take action because it could lead to reputation damage?
Since this is a training video it will be watched by many ... I am not happy and truly worried about my reputation and the damage this might do to my career.
thank you.

Comment: I believe this is more of a legal question than a workplace one.  As such it's likely this will be closed.  You may want to ask this in the Law Stack Exchange forum.  Another option would be to consult an attorney.

Comment: Where in the world are you? Do they have a written (email, chat) or voice recorded ("I'll turn on the recording" => "okay") approval from you to be recorded at all?

Comment: @nvoigt - in MS Teams, when recordings are started there is a pop-up message that appears at the top of everyone's meeting window indicating that recording has started and persists until you take the positive action to click the "Dismiss" button.

Comment: Please add a country tag. Your answers will vary from "haha, your fault" to "just tell them not to, they are bound by law". There is no global privacy rules or laws.

Comment: I voted to close since you never really asked your employer. I would simply ask the employer if your face can be taken out because you were not at your best. However, I don't think it is wise to threaten legal actions. You're essentially in a "public" space and if you are in the USA, most states allow recording within public space.

Answer (score 7):

1. Your reputation will be fine.
2. Taking / threatening legal action you run [the risk of the Streisand Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streisand_effect#:%7E:text=The%20Streisand%20effect%20is%20a,information%2C%20often%20via%20the%20Internet.) and creating the inverse result: instead of "Haha, what's-her-name accidentally appeared in this training video" you'll be known as "what's-her-name threatened legal action over a video".
3. Rescinding the use of your image for company use would be on the same level of legal action and, unfortunately, Teams and your webcam-in-use light provides adequate notification you are being recorded — you are at fault.
4. Give the request some more time. While high on yours, this is probably very low on their priority list. Follow up with a face-to-face / phone call / webcam meeting after a few days to reiterate the importance — email can get lost or forgotten easily.

Comment: "you are at fault" you may want to specify a country here, in many juristictions, it only counts as consent if you actually and in writing *consented*. Neither your webcam light nor a third party application is legally binding and I'm pretty sure Microsoft themselves would only claim to be "as good as we can", not failsafe or legally binding.

Comment: Not legal advice. OP is at fault for turning on their camera, during a known recording session, and leaving it on for 30 minutes without seeing indications. I can’t comment on legal jurisdiction but as a professional I don’t see it ending well.

Comment: Well, you may still want to add your juristiction, because where I live, an email of "I saw I am actually on camera, I do no consent to my picture being used" is enough for the company to not touch that video with a ten foot pole. And where I live, that is normal and not a reason to fire anybody, not that they *could*, because where I live you actually need a *reason* for that. So... legal framework matters a lot, even if you don't use it.

Answer (score 3):

First, your appearance matters more to you than to others - few will think badly of you for not looking your best. The distraction and not paying attention is probably a bigger issue.

Second, I think it's more relevant that only one person had a camera on, and the video is intended to be viewed by other people later. Those people are going to think there is a reason this one attendee is showing on the screen, and it's going to confuse them. For that reason alone, your employer will probably want to edit the video.

Third, they need only edit it before they publish it. If it's already been published, they need to replace the live version with an edited version. I'm not sure how you know they haven't done it, but I'm assuming you know because the confusing and unflattering version is still somewhere public. I don't know the audience for this video: do they come in waves such as new hires every few months, or a more continuous thing? If it's waves, the person who needs to edit may plan to do the edit "in the next few weeks" before the next set of new hires arrive. This may mean you don't need to do anything to get it edited.

Fourth, attempting to force the person to do something they already said they would do, on your timetable, is rarely a good plan at work, especially if they outrank you. Making vaguely legal sounding references to your reputation will make it worse, not better. That's just how people are. Someone will end up saying "it wasn't me who sat down in front of a hot camera all dishevelled and messy, then couldn't pay attention for half an hour!" You need a different way to get assurance that the audience for your mistake will be as small as possible.

Here is a possible wording for a followup email:

> Hey, I couldn't help myself, I checked the live video again and my solo starring performance as "dishevelled attendee" is still up there for all to see. I know the confusion for learners of only one attendee being shown is small, but combined with my embarrassment over my appearance, I do think it's time-sensitive to replace the video with an edited one. I know you plan to do it, and have other things to take care of. Can you let me know when you think the [firstname]-less version will go live?

Word it as you would but do include:

- an acknowledgment that not everyone sees this as a big deal **but you do**
- some other reasons for doing the edit besides your own cringe factor
- a reminder they agreed to do it
- a question (when will it be done?) rather than a command/request (please do it as soon as you can)
- acknowledging that they choose when to do it and they have other stuff to do (your note is of course designed to raise the priority of this item to them)
- no mention of legal obligation, reputation, etc
- a generally friendly and cheerful tone

If this email is ignored, or you get a response like "actually I've decided I don't have time to do it, it's no big deal" then you can **consider** going to your manager over it, but be very careful if you do. Reminding your manager about that time you were inappropriate and how important it is to you to make that go away could backfire. It's possible that this embarrassment will be the tuition you pay to "remember to check if your camera is on" school - a school most of us have attended by now, often at larger expense than this. Some people need to repeat the lesson several times before it sticks.

Answer (score 1):

How many disheveled and unflattering people have you seen in your whole life? Not zero.

How many do you remember? Definitely zero. You couldn't ID a single one unless it was within the last hour. Nobody cares.

If it still bothers you, go deliberately look up unflattering pictures of yourself, and then try to deliberately find them in the internet. Google-image/Facebook search your most unflattering picture and see if even they can ID you. If the largest AI systems in the world can't link your unflattering face to you, nobody else can, and nobody else will care.

Answer (score 0):

You did not tell us where you live. You already got answers from other countries and they are probably fine in their respective juristictions.

However, if you reside in an area where the [gdpr](/questions/tagged/gdpr) applies (large parts of Europe), I suggest you remind them of this fact.

Write an email to the editor/person recording/publishing along the lines of:

> Hello Editor, I noticed I was caught on video for our training video. That was never my intention. I do not consent to using video of me in any form. Sorry for any inconvenience this causes, I hope you can easily edit me out.

If you think you need more authority then this, put your manager and/or HR in CC. They have had so many GDPR training(s) in the last year(s), they know *exactly* what the procedure is or at least should be. They also know exactly, that no button, software or webcam light you ignored is a legally valid replacement for getting written consent from you before they publish this.

Assuming your job description does not include appearences on camera, you should be fine, they will edit you out without any repercussions.